# Comma as a separator vs. comma as a delimiter

Tags: javascript

In [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTEqr0IlFKY#t=8m01s), the speaker says:

> "Some people get confused about how commas work. They think they
>   should be delimiters rather than separators. Now you can think about
>   them either way."

I don't understand the difference between a delimiter and a separator (if there is one). The implication in the video is that now (that trailing commas are valid), one can think of them as delimiters, rather than separators...

Btw the language in question is JavaScript. From my understanding, the comma token has two meanings:

- as an operator (rarely used)
- as a separator (in argument and parameter lists, array and object literals, etc.)

I'm not sure how a comma delimiter fits into this...

Comment: Why does this matter?

Comment: @jfriend00 If there is a difference between the terms delimiter and separator, I want to know it... I like to know stuff `:)`

Comment: @jfriend00 Watch the video. If the IE people weren't thinking as narrowly as you, maybe we wouldn't have yet another javascript portability snafu...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Good question. BTW the speaker is Douglas Crockford, senior JavaScript architect at Yahoo, known for popularizing JSON and author of [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do). It's a good think you pay attention to detail, especially when watching a Crockford video, as he rarely wastes any breath for stuff that don't matter.

Comment: @YannisRizos Yea, I know Crockford. He's a great educator. `:)`

Comment: If you're asking about the words, wouldn't http://english.stackexchange.com/ be a better place for this question?

Comment: @S.Lott Could be. I may try there too.

Comment: It seems like people are hung up on a semantic issue.  We've known for years and years that older versions of IE don't accept a trailing comma after the last array element.  This is just a fact.  Therefore, if you want your code to work, you can't put that extra comma.  That means that you need to think of commas as separators (they only go between elements, not after the last element).  This is NOTHING new and has been required for good interoperability for a long time.  Just because ECMA5 has now made that trailing comma legal doesn't change how you have to code for interoperability.

Comment: @jfriend00: I personally do not like the trailing comma because it seems a bit inconsistent to me: why is it allowed for array elements and not for function arguments?

Comment: @Giorgio - I don't like the extra trailing comma either.  I have no idea why it's different for arrays vs. arguments.

Comment: @jfriend00: I think it is meant to help developers when doing copy-and-pasting with array items that are written one per line. The comma after the last item is allowed because the extra effort of removing / adding the comma where needed would kill productivity.

Answer (score 17):

If you consider the comma as a separator, you use a comma between two items of a sequence to separate them, if you consider it as a delimiter, you put it after each item to indicate where an item ends. See the examples below:

**Comma as a separator**

```
var myCars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW" ];
```

**Comma as a delimiter**

```
var myCars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", ];
```

I think the video says that you can think of commas both as separators and delimiters because both array examples above are valid. On the other hand in Javascript you can only use the comma as a separator in the parameter list of a function, e.g.

```
foo(a, b, c) // separator, OK
```

is valid whereas

```
foo(a, b, c,) // delimiter, NOT OK!
```

is not valid.

**EDIT**

As far as I understand, according to the wikipedia page a **separator** is a special case of a **delimiter**, namely one that is put between the different text regions whose boundaries need to be marked. In fact, the wikipedia page names comma-**separated** values as an example use of delimiters.
So, in general you can use delimiters in different ways: before, after, on both sides of the portion of text to be marked.

The reason why I interpreted **delimiter** as "marker that is put after an item" in the Javascript context was motivated by the array literal example, which is valid also for C, C++, and Java (I think I have seen at least one question on stack overflow regarding this topic).

Another example of similar but different use of a character is that of semicolon as a statement delimiter (C, C++, Java, Ada, ...) and as a statement separator (Pascal). Therefore

```
if (a > 0)
    printf("Positive\n");
else
    printf("Non positive\n");
```

is correct C code whereas

```
IF a > 0 THEN
    WriteLn('Positive'); (* Syntax error here! *)
ELSE
    WriteLn('Non positive');
```

is no correct Pascal code.

Maybe **terminator** would be a better / less ambiguous term than **delimiter**?
E.g. one could formulate the quote as follows: "Some people get confused about how commas work. They think they should be **item terminators** rather than **item separators**. Now (in many cases) you can think about them either way."

Comment: Yes, in parameter lists the comma must be used as a separator, whereas in array literals the comma can either be used as a separator or a delimiter. Or in layman's terms: You can put a comma after the last array element, but you don't have to.

Comment: While your answer does explain the quote from my question quite well, the Wikipedia page for ["Delimiter"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter) provides different definitions. According to that article, a delimiter specifies the boundary *between* regions. So, the "comma as a separator" example from your question above would be called the comma field delimiter, while the "comma as a delimiter" example isn't represented anywhere on that Wiki page.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Wikipedia is just a reference like any other reference, it's not the only reference.

Comment: @CapeCodGunny Yes, I'm just pointing out that there are confronting definitions. I would like to see definitions from other references, too.

Answer (score 7):

A separator would be put between two values, separating them.

```
one,two,three
```

A delimiter would delimit a field - it would be on both sides.

```
,one,two,three,
```

When taken this way, it makes little difference, so long as one can extract the separate fields out.

This is a completely different issue to that of usage of a comma in a programming language such as javascript. It is about delimiting/separating values within a string.

Comment: Ah yes, this makes sense.

Comment: I disagree with your delimiter explanation. Based on your explanation it would be ,one,,two,,three, now the delimiter is on both sides.

Comment: @CapeCodGunny - You are misinterpreting. The example I gave has a comma before and after _each_ value. The commas not at the very start and end of the string serve as the end delimiter _and_ start delimiter.

Comment: @Oded This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter) provides different definitions. According to it, your first example would be a field delimiter, while your second example isn't represented in that article at all.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Fair enough, I was really thinking about a file format like CSV, where commas separate fields, and double quotes (") delimit them. Probably not exactly what Douglas Crockford was talking about.

Comment: Word of caution! `var myNumbers = ['one','two','three', ];` (comma in the end) would give array length as 3 but because of a comma in the front `var myNumbers = [,'one','two','three'];` gives length as 4.

Answer (score 0):

> "They think they should be delimiters"

In other words, looks like some people think commas should set boundaries or limits. A beginning and an end-

Think in CSV readers. CSV readers allow you to set the "delimiter" and the "separator". For the sake of the answer, lets change comma as delimiter with a single quote. So

```
# Field A, Field B, Field C
'Value 1','Value 2',
```

The single quote (') acts as a delimiter here. It states a beginning and an end. It comprises the beginning and the end of a sequence of elements that must be read as one. Otherwise, the sequence could be readen as different fields, tokenizing the row in more values than fields. This makes sense because `Value 1` could be also `Value, 1` and we don't want it to be readen has 2 different fields.

On the other hand. the comma here is a separator, which doesn't bring implicit any beginning or end, just sequentiality. *New value after this*. Given the above example, the trailing comma is just separating `Value 2` from Field C's value. An empty value btw.

I get the feeling that this is, somewhat, what Crowford introduce when he says that IE used to read the trailing comma as a separator (sequence). If we extrapolate the CSV example to the old versions of IE, we find the IE translated the trailing comma into a separator, hence allocated one more position in the array. And empty position btw, distorting the true length.

It's a way to say that some people think that, if Microsoft developers had understood the comma as a delimiter, they wouldn't have allowed the trailing comma, hence the extra and empty array position. Or they would, but they would get rid of it and ignore this last position as the newer versions of ES seems to do.

A matter of perception.